Error: cannot resolve method 'getName' in 'Cookie'
Created a project in Intellij Idea Ultimate with 
Generations: JavaEE 
Template: Web Application
Language: Java 
Build System: Maven 
Specifications: Web profile
Version: JavaEE 8
I'm using tomcat9.
I'm trying to get cookies out of the request in servlet, but I'm getting errors:

Cannot resolve method 'getName' in 'Cookie'
Cannot resolve method 'getValue' in 'Cookie'

What could be the problem?
I'm a newbie so I'm hoping for your help.
Servlet:
package servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import static java.lang.System.out;

@WebServlet( urlPatterns = "/degree_elements")
public class MassIndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        Cookie [] cookie=request.getCookies();
        for(Cookie c:cookie)
        {
            out.println(cookie.getName());
            out.println(cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
}

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>servlets</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ex3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Ex3</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

